# matlab inputparser

Tags: matlab

I want to validate input arguments with `inputparser`, where the input arguments have  `2 required inputs` and `varargin`.

```
  function = myfun( input1,input2,varargin)
  p = inputParser;
  addRequired(p,'input1',@(x) any(validatestring(x,{'sum','sub'})))
  addRequired(p,'input2',@ischar)

  parse(p,input1,input2,varargin{:})  ??
```

How can i validate varargin where my varargin is with variable length.

like : `myfun('sum','hallo','Name','address',...)`

Comment: That works doesnt it? It'll say that the first invalid (e.g. non-targeted string) didn't match any of the valid parameters. What do you want to have happen? Ignore the invalid ones?

Answer (score 0):

If (and only if) your variable input arguments take the form of parameter-value pairs, you can do this:

```
function result = myfun(varargin)
    p = inputParser;
    p.addRequired('input1', @validation1);
    p.addRquuired('input2', @validation2);
    p.KeepUnmatched = true;
    p.parse(varargin{:});
    params = p.Unmatched;
end
```

Otherwise, you are stuck with manually parsing the inputs, I am afraid:

```
function result = myfun(input1, input2, varargin)
    p = inputParser;
    p.addRequired('input1', @validation1);
    p.addRquuired('input2', @validation2);
    p.parse(input1, input2);

    for item in varargin:
        % MANUAL VALIDATION GOES HERE
    end

end
```